# Add the same page to a pdf multiple times

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I found a code that allows me to add several PDF files to another PDF.

Basically what the code do is fill an array with strings (the names of the files you want to gather) and then loop the command insertpage.

Here's the part of the code that allows to gather several PDF's on a single one

```
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        
        Set PartDocs(i) = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        PartDocs(i).Open mypath & Trim(a(i))
        If i Then
    
            ni = PartDocs(i).GetNumPages()
            PartDocs(0).InsertPages n - 1, PartDocs(i), 0, ni, True
            
            n = n + ni
    
            PartDocs(i).Close
            Set PartDocs(i) = Nothing
        Else
            n = PartDocs(0).GetNumPages()
        End If
    Next
```

It works great if you have several files, but it doesn't work at all if you are trying to add the same file repeatedly. What the code do in this case is only ad once each file you put in the array.

If you fill an array of 5 elements with the same file, the resultant PDF only will have 1 page corresponding to the file in the array. If you fill with 2 (even if you alternate the names in the array) the resultant PDF will only have 2 pages (one for each file)

Is there any way to add multiple times the same file to a PDF?

Comment: Have you stepped though and watched what happens when it hits a duplicate file?

Comment: @K J let me explain, this is because the images are actually QR codes that should be paste on every single product. Each QR is related to tipe of item an the date of production so if we produce 100 items in a single day we have to produce 100 stickers with the same QR code. After that I print in a single sheet several QR codes since we print that QR's in a common DIN-A4 sheet by using the printing option "multiple" in adobe acrobat dc

Comment: @TimWilliams do you mean a duplicate file on the array or when I run this portion of code again? If it is the second one then the current generated file replace the previous one, it doesn't add any aditional page to the previous file. If you meant a duplicate file in the array then when the loop starts to work everything looks like it would work, it add a new page to partdocs(0) with the corresponding pdf file on the array. I can't see directly how it looks the pdf file on each step, only when I save it after the loop and it only add pages if the files on the array are diferent